# Value of protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Equatable' Swift

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I'm trying to remove "songDict" from "libraryArray" but it triggers an error.

```
var libraryArray = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "LibraryArray") as! [Dictionary<String, Any>]

var songDict = Dictionary<String, Any>()

var arr = libraryArray.filter {$0 != songDict}
```

And here's the error.
**Value of protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Equatable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols**

Comment: `var songDict: Dictionary<String, Any>()` would not compile. it should be either var `songDict: Dictionary<String, Any>` (define the var and its type but no init) or `var songDict = Dictionary<String, Any>()` (define var with type and init)

Comment: Unrelated but there is `dictionary(forKey` in `UserDefaults`. You should use `value(forKey` only if you know what KVC is and you really need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you cannot compare two dictionaries like that as they dont conform to `Equatable` protocol. It will be better to use a struct for your data model instead of `Dictionary`.

```
struct Library: Equatable {
    let id: String
    ...
}
```

But if you don't want to do that, you can still check for equality with your dictionaries by equating the value of any keys in it.

```
    var arr = libraryArray.filter { (dict) -> Bool in
        dict["id"] as? String == songDict["id"] as? String
    }
```